# Tensorflow remove a list of elements from a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to remove a list of possible values from a shape 1 tensor, with Tensorflow code

For example

```
values = [1,3,5]
tensor = [1,2,205,23,5]
remove(tensor, values) -> [2,205,23]
```

And I would need this to be as scalable as possible related to values as they can be up to 10k for my use case.
Is there any better than iterating over the 10k solution?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution would be `tf.sets.difference`, which returns a sparse tensor with indices and values:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

values = tf.constant([1,3, 5])
tensor = tf.constant([1,2,205,23,5])

tensor = tf.sets.difference(tf.expand_dims(tensor, axis=0), tf.expand_dims(values, axis=0)).values
```

```
tf.Tensor([  2  23 205], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
```

You could also try using `tf.repeat` and `tf.boolean_mask` if you want to keep the order:

```
import tensorflow as tf

values = tf.constant([1, 3, 5])
tensor = tf.constant([1,2,205,23,5])

repeat_values = tf.repeat(values, repeats=tf.shape(tensor)[0], axis=0)
repeat_tensor = tf.repeat(tensor, repeats=tf.shape(values)[0], axis=0)
tensor = tf.boolean_mask(repeat_tensor, tf.not_equal(repeat_tensor, repeat_values))[::tf.shape(values)[0]]
# tf.Tensor([  2 205  23], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
```

But IMO `tf.sets.difference` is more elegant.